# Meaning of Cobwebbed in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, literature

> ...Rain, yet so fine it could scarcely fall but rather floated. It clung to everything it touched; the rushes in the deep choked ditches of the sea-marsh were bowed down with it, the small black cattle looked **cobwebbed** with it, their horns were jewelled with it.
>
> ***The fox in the Attic***;
>   Author: Richard Hughes

My question is:
What does this word mean in this context?
Cobweb is a spider's old and dusty web, but also can be some kind of confusion.

Comment: My guess: the droplets covered the cattle, reminding of a cobweb covered with droplets.

Comment: @sumelic  I'll do that, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be cobwebbed, without any 'with' or 'in' or similar afterwards, means to be covered in cobwebs.

If there's a 'with' or such, it means to be covered with whatever-it-is in a manner that resembles being covered in cobwebs.

In this case, the cattle are covered with droplets of water in such a way as to make people think of them being covered in cobwebs. Not that it could be mistaken for that, but just that it reminds people of it.

Comment: Thank you! By reading the text again, your explanation makes sense.